# Manual vs manually

Tags: usage, grammaticality-in-context

To give some context to the question:

> Procedures of type X require **manually (manual)** tuning the weights...

Which is the correct form?

Answer (score 10):

*Manually* is the adverb.  *Manual* is (in this context) the adjective.

*Tuning* can be either a verb or a noun; however, in your example, *tuning the weights* is a [gerund phrase](http://www.k12reader.com/term/gerund-phrase/) using the verb.  Here you want to modify the verb within the phrase, so use the adverb:

> The procedure requires **manually** tuning the weights.

If instead you wanted to modify the noun *tuning*, use the adjective.

> The procedure requires **a manual** tuning **of** the weights.

Comment: +1 but I don't think the "a" before "manual" is strictly necessary in the second example

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of expressing this statement:

> 1.....require manually turning the weights...

which is not an idiomatic construction.

> 2.....require manual turning of the weights....

using the adjective to describe the gerund construction. This is an improvement but not ideal.

> 3.....require turning the weights manually (or) by hand...

which is the best option although still a bit awkward.

The problem is the omission of the *agent* who is required to turn the weights.

The statement would read most easily if you wrote:

> require operators to turn the weights manually (or) by hand.

Comment: "require manually turning the weights" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @Kevin Try testing *require manually* against *require manual* on Ngram viewer.

Comment: "Adverb verb object" and "verb object adverb" are [both perfectly idiomatic.](https://bit.ly/2I7A4Bu)

Comment: @Kevin My argument is not that the construction of the example is ungrammatical but simply that few people use the language in that manner (which is to say *idiomatic*) as Ngram illustrates. But I'm happy to agree to differ.

Comment: But Ngrams shows that people use it that way all the time

Answer (score 0):

Whichever of these forms you use, the writing style is ugly and impersonal. I would write "You will need to tune the weights by hand." But of course that only works if the whole document is written in a more direct personal style.